# Media query/any other solution to apply CSS on both pop-up and desktop

Tags: css, sass, popup, media-queries

I have the same content to be displayed on a pop-up and desktop view.
I already used media queries to adjust the content on desktop/mobile view. But in desktop view, the same content needs to be displayed on a pop-up with different margins.
How can I achieve this? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: show some relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Just add different `margin` that will overwrite default one based on parent class of the component - in your case it will be pop-up class.

If you do not want to increase CSS specificity - you may try add class modificator (eg `component--big-margin`) if you are using CSS methodology like BEM.